# Suppose we have a matrix, 100 rows and 100 columns, of 2-byte integers

Tags: memory-management, matrix, linked-list

a.)Suppose we have a matrix, 100 rows and 100 columns, of 2-byte integers, how many bytes does it occupy?

-I wrote that this would be (100 * 100 * 2 = 20,00 bytes) I had no problem with this part, the next part is where I am lost.

b.) Suppose X% of the entries are non-zero. We choose to represent the matrix by a linked list of nodes representing the non-zero values. Each node contains, using the least space possible,

Row,Column,Value,Pointer to next node

In addition, there is a 2-byte pointer to the first node in the list. How many bytes do we need
altogether?

-Basically I know that I'm given 2 bytes for each starting node pointer, 6 bytes minimum per node. Although I am not sure as to how represent this as a formula.Any help is appreciated

Comment: Which programming language, os, architecture?

Comment: How big are your pointers? You say the initial pointer is 2 bytes, but are all the other pointers 2 bytes as well?